# Splitting/dividing an array as evenly as possible

Tags: ruby

I’m trying to split/divide an array as evenly as possible.

How can I split the array like this? If the array has an even amount of values, then I also want it to just be divided by two. Are there any methods that do this?

```rb
array = [5, 1, 3, 8, 7]

array.method_i_need

#=> [[5, 1, 3], [8, 7]]
```

I tried using `#each_slice` but I couldn’t get it to split the array like I want it to.

Comment: "I couldn’t get it to split the array like I want it to" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: First calculate the highest array index which is supposed to be included into the first part. Then use the fact that `array[x..y]` produces an array size from index x up to (including) index y. If y equals -1, it denotes the last element.

Comment: @JörgWMittag He is the new contributor, he doesn't know the way forum works. Down-voting him doesn't do any good. We have to first explain him the way forum works.

Comment: Wouldn't a split into `[[5, 7], [1, 3, 8]]` make more sense, when the amount should be as similar as possible in both nested arrays?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question clearly. So I used the following logic to achieve your answer.

array = [5, 1, 3, 8, 7]

Code

```
# Determine the size of each slice
size = (array.size / 2.0).ceil 
# Split the array into slices
result = array.each_slice(size).to_a 
p result
```

output

```
#=>[[5, 1, 3], [8, 7]]
```